# Safe to include high missing percentage variables

Tags: regression, logistic, missing-data

I'm in the process of building a logistic regression model. Some variables having more than 50% missing values. After missing imputation with zero value, they are helping to improve accuracy significantly. Should i include these variable? For example, development data set consists of 1 million records of retail customers. The objective of the model is whether bank should offer Certificate of Deposit (Fixed Deposit) product. We are considering historical data. A very few customers own this product so the variables for this product are having very few values populated and 80% missing. I used to remove all the variables having % missing greater than 50. Am i doing wrong from a statistical point of view?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on 'imputation with zero'.  This implies imputation to a constant value which is not appropriate unless perhaps the true unknown prevalence of the condition is extremely low.  Multiple imputation is often required.  When using multiple imputation there is no limit of missingness in the sense that the alternative (removing the variable or removing the missing observations) is worse.  Current guidance is to make one imputation per percent of incomplete observations when using multiple imputation.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply. Could you explain " imputation to a constant value which is not appropriate unless perhaps " a little bit with example? Would single imputation be correct for high % of missing values even if we know the missing implies not applicable for that portion of population? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Special considerations are needed for 'not applicable'.  That sort of thing has been discussed at length in the `IMPUTE` email discussion group (see http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms for a link).  To my knowledge although multiple imputation has been studied with a high proportion of missings, single imputation has not.